# Can 'nor' be used to negate a positive statement?

Tags: conjunctions, neither-nor

I would like to ask whether the following constructions are correct:

**1. He refused to listen to me. Nor is he ready to leave.**

or

**2. We missed the plane. Nor did we catch the train.**

From [this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53728/using-nor-in-a-list-without-neither) I understand that we can use 'nor' to negate a sentence after another negative sentence, as in an example there:

**I wasn't going to play dead. Nor was I going to hide.**

Note however that formally the first sentences are not negative in examples 1 and 2, so I am not one hundred percent sure about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a very good question.

The two examples you gave are not negative (i.e., they do not contain negated verbs), and *nor* is generally limited to following negative sentence, that is true.

However, the ‘negative’ part of that is sometimes more semantic than syntactic/grammatical. If the **meaning** of the preceding sentence has an element of being negative in nature about it, then you **can** use *nor*, as long as it makes sense semantically to do so.

In both your example sentences, there is an element of negativity: refusing is a ‘negative action’ semantically (the negative of assenting), and missing a train can just about be considered one as well.

Your second example to me sounds perfectly fine, and it is something that many native speakers would say without a second thought. Your first example sounds a little bit odd, but I suspect that's due to the lack of parallelism between the two sentences in it: what does leaving have to do with listening to you? If you had chosen a more parallel example, there would be no problem; for example:

> He refused to talk to me; nor would he listen to what I had to say.

Answer (score 1):

*Nor* only makes sense if you can use *or* in the first place.  The two things in both your examples are not mutually exclusive which is when *or* / *nor* needs to be used.

> He refused to listen to me. Nor is he ready to leave.
>
> He did listen to me or he's ready to leave - Doesn't work.

Really the conjunction *and* is better, but there is no negative version of *and* in English (unless you work in electronics...)

A *neither* construction will allow you to use *nor*:

> He neither listened to me nor was ready to leave.

Comment: I don't understand quite what you mean by “_nor_ only makes sense if you can use _or_ in the first place”. I can't think of any context to use _nor_ where _or_ would also work. They are kind of mutually exclusive. _Nor_ is simply _not… either_ in this usage, which seems rather orthogonal to _or_.